# TreeView in GridView

Tags: asp.net, wpf, gridview, treeview

I know there must be a way to do this, and perhaps someone has already done it. I googled like crazy but found nothing at all. Anyway, what I want to do is have a TreeView in the first column of a GridView using WPF, which can expand and collapse and that will show/hide the row it belongs to, pretty much something like this (the demo is for ASP.NET, I want to be able to do the same in WPF):

[DevExpress demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/Selection/FocusedNode.aspx)

In our company we bought Infragistics controls, but it doesn't have a built in solution, we're trying to avoid spending a lot of time coding this solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're not using the right search terms... IMO, what you're actually looking for is not a GridView with a TreeView inside it, but rather a TreeView with columns.

Here are a some samples of TreeViews with columns (often called TreeList or TreeListView) :

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/03/01/541206.aspx

Comment: That sounds about right, I think the second link will work for me. I will test it during the course of the day and let you know if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics support similar scenario, see their [overview](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wintree.aspx#Features) - for WinTree control.

They can also do this [for grids](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wingrid.aspx#Features) (see under Hierarchical display).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's for Windows Forms, I'm using WPF.