# Treeview inside GridView in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I have seen these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973054/treeview-in-gridview) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578905/treeview-nested-in-a-gridview), but they are in wpf or Asp, I was wonder it is possible to do that in C# or if it can't be done is there any possible way to do this with other components
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yah, TreeList controls are common in Winforms as well.  Go shopping.

Comment: What about a free one:D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at this example from CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3225/TreeListView

Also, if you are looking for an enterprise solution, check out [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/)